# R-Markdown: Rendering to PDF and appending to existing PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, rendering

I am using RMarkdown to create a set of 6,000 letters. I am using parameters to create custom inputs into the document. I am using a loop to render the PDFs and calling it as follows:

```
for (i in 1:6000) {
  rmarkdown::render(
    input = "/template/letter.Rmd", 
    output_dir = "/output/",
    output_file = paste0("report", i)
  )
}
```

Now, this creates a 6,000 separate PDFs, but I would like to have it in one long document. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to use `rmarkdown::render()` and have it append the current PDF it generates onto the existing one? If I set `output_file = report`, for example, it will simply overwrite the existing PDF in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the outputs using a toolkit for pdf files. For instance, you can use the [staplr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/staplr/staplr.pdf) package:

```
library(staplr)
ofiles <- c()
for (i in 1:6000) {
 ofile <- rmarkdown::render(
   input =  "/template/letter.Rmd",
   output_dir = "/output/",
   output_file = paste0("report", i)
 )
 ofiles <- c(ofiles, ofile)
}
staple_pdf(input_files = ofiles, output_filepath = "/output/all-in-one.pdf")
```

In Linux, you can also merge the pdf files using `pdftk`:

```
cd /output/
pdftk report*.pdf cat output all-in-one.pdf
```